# Get custom field value on entries.onBeforeSaveEntry event

Tags: custom-field

I am trying to get a custom field value on `entries.onBeforeSaveEntry`, event.  So I can perform some action depending on the value of that field.

```
craft()->on('entries.onBeforeSaveEntry', function(Event $event)
{
    $entry = $event->params['entry'];
    $entry->publishOnMobileApp;  //publishOnMobileApp is the field handle
});
```

Now this line.

```
$entry->publishOnMobileApp;
```

Returns

```
Craft\MultiOptionsFieldData Object ( 
    [_options:Craft\MultiOptionsFieldData:private] => 
Array ( [0] => Craft\OptionData Object 
( 
    [label] => Yes [value] => yes [selected] => )
)
   [storage:ArrayObject:private] =&gt; Array()
)
```

I am not sure how exactly I can access just the value of the field (which is "yes" in this case) so I can perform a check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at the [docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/dropdown-fields.html#templating) it's the same in PHP as in Twig

```
foreach($entry->getFieldValue('publishOnMobileApp')->options as $option){
    if($option->selected){
         // $option->label is selected
    }
}
```